# Инициализация libavcodec

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

Возникает проблема при регистрации кодеков и форматов. Кусок кода:

```
av_register_all();  
avformat_network_init();
```

Также пробовала такой вариант:

```
avcodec_register_all();
```

И сама ошибка:
LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl avcodec_register_all(void)" (?avcodec_register_all@@YAXXZ)

Думаю на ошибку компоновщика, но я указывала дополнительные каталоги с lib и include.

UPD 1:
Спасибо за ссылку, это было одно из первого, что я прочла.
В коде используются сторонние библиотеки, но:
- библиотеки для компоновщика указаны
- разрядность совпадает с компилируемым кодом

Comment: 1. Найдите файл с реализацией `avcodec_register_all` используя поиск файлов. 2. Проверьте что этот файл попадает в `#include`. Добавьте его с помощью `#include ` Если это не помагает, файл есть и подключен - то проверяйте настройки компилятора, почитайте опции компилятора и инфу по слову `extern "С"` и про настройку типов вызовов (cdecl stdcall и т д) либо пропущен namespace. Настройки "типа/вида" вызова должны совпадать в обьявлении и в реализации.

Answer (score 0):

Странный момент что импортируется mangled имя функции. Возможно у вас проблема c заголовками libav. Попробуйте насильно подавлять name mangling оборачивая инклюды этих заголовочных файлов:

```
extern "C"
{
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
}
```